# What will be the values of these parameters when GetQueuedCompletionStatus() return FALSE?

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

There are two reasons that can cause `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to fail (return `FALSE`), the first is because the completion port handle associated with it is closed while the call is outstanding, this will be the case if `lpOverlapped` is `NULL`.

The second reason (which is the one I care about) is if the IO operation (for example: `WSARecv()`) fails. This is what the documentation says about this situation:

> If *lpOverlapped is not NULL and the function dequeues a completion
>   packet for a failed I/O operation from the completion port, the
>   function stores information about the failed operation in the
>   variables pointed to by lpNumberOfBytes, lpCompletionKey, and
>   lpOverlapped. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

I do not find this to be very clear as to what the values of `lpNumberOfBytes`, `lpCompletionKey`, and `lpOverlapped` will be. Will these parameters contain the same values that I supplied when calling `WSARecv()`? I suppose that this is more likely because how else am I suppose to know what IO operation caused the failure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an I/O operation fails then `lpCompletionKey` and `lpOverlapped` will be the values that were supplied when you initiated the I/O operation using whichever API was used (`WSASend()`, `WSARecv()`, etc.). This is how you identify the 'per device' data and the 'per operation' data for the I/O operation in question.

`lpNumberOfBytes` is likely to be zero in error situations though I tend to deal with it the same as for the non error case as I never use the resulting value (or the buffer contents) during error handling anyway.